# Compare two list and get first value after condition is satisfied

Tags: python, list

I have two list with some values in common:

```
a = [200.04, 300.87, 400.19, 500.67, 600.86, 700.19, 800.48]
b = [200.04, 600.86]
```

How can I compare the two list to get the first element in list a after the same element in list b?
Expected output would be:

```
c = [300.87, 700.19]
```

Thank you!

Comment: What if the value in `b` is `800.48`?

Comment: maybe return a NaN, actually I don't think I have this problem in my lists, but its a good point @Nick

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? Have you tried anything, done any research?

Comment: Does the order of `b` matter — should the answer be the same if `b = [600.86, 200.04]`?

Comment: @AMC I've tried using list comprehension but I couldn't get the first number in list a after comparison with b. I didn't actually indexing. Now that I'm thinking about it I could use np.mask as well ;) Thank you!

Comment: @Mark Meyer not really, the order doesn't matter as I could sort later

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would zip the list with itself and return the second part of the tuple when the first part is in `b`:

```
a = [200.04, 300.87, 400.19, 500.67, 600.86, 700.19, 800.48]
b = [200.04, 600.86]

[n for m, n in zip(a, a[1:]) if m in b]
# [300.87, 700.19]
```

This is potentially inefficient if `b` is large, but handles edge cases well — such as different orders or the final item from `a` being part of `b`.

Comment: That's nice. Avoids all the problems with `index`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use index positions to solve this.

```
a = [200.04, 300.87, 400.19, 500.67, 600.86, 700.19, 800.48]
b = [200.04, 600.86]
c = []
for x in b:
    c.append(a[a.index(x)+1])
```

If you run this program, then `c = [300.87, 700.19]`

Comment: what if b has 800.48  in the elements? your for loop will crush

Answer (score 1):

you could use a list comprehension with `list.index`:

```
[a[a[:-1].index(e) + 1] for e in b]
```

output:

```
[300.87, 700.19]
```

to avoid so many slicing:

```
s = a[:-1]
[a[s.index(e) + 1] for e in b]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a verbose way of doing this, which checks that the value in `b` actually exists in `a` so as to avoid errors if it doesn't:

```
a = [200.04, 300.87, 400.19, 500.67, 600.86, 700.19, 800.48]
b = [200.04, 600.86]
c = []
for v in b:
    try:
        i = a.index(v)
    except ValueError:
        i = -1
    if i >= 0 and i < len(a) - 1:
        c.append(a[i+1])
    else:
        c.append(float('nan'))

print(c)
```

Output:

```
[300.87, 700.19]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just iterate through your input list `a` and append the successors to list `c` whenever the item is element of list `b`.

```
a = [200.04, 300.87, 400.19, 500.67, 600.86, 700.19, 800.48]
b = [200.04, 600.86]

c = []
for index, item in enumerate(a):
    if item in b and index < len(a) - 1:
        c.append(a[index+1])
```

This checks the index not to extend bounds, so whenever there is no successor, the list is left unchanged.